# Merge Tables from rerun purrr output in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm sure it's pretty easy, but I'm fairly new to R and can't figure it out. What I want to do is create one table that binds all the tables together. The column order changes on every table, so I need to specify the variables names to be bound together. I just don't know how to merge all the individual tables from the output as one dataframe. Any other suggestions on how to get 4 conditions with 4 levels each randomised, that would be amazing!

This is the code so far

```
purrr::rerun(20, data.frame(
cry = sample(4, 1, replace = F),
laugh = sample(4, 1, replace = F),
babble = sample(4, 1, replace = F),
aversive = sample(4, 1, replace = F)
) %>%
sample(4)
)
```

Looking forward to any help!!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

```
purrr::rerun(20, data.frame(
  cry = sample(4, 1, replace = F),
  laugh = sample(4, 1, replace = F),
  babble = sample(4, 1, replace = F),
  aversive = sample(4, 1, replace = F)
) %>%
  sample(4)
) %>% 
  bind_rows()

   laugh cry babble aversive
1      2   1      2        3
2      2   1      2        4
3      1   4      4        1
4      3   3      1        1
5      4   1      4        3
6      2   2      1        3
7      2   4      4        4
8      1   3      1        3
9      4   4      3        3
10     2   2      2        1
11     4   2      2        4
12     3   3      3        4
13     4   1      4        3
14     4   2      1        2
15     4   4      2        4
16     1   1      1        2
17     3   3      4        3
18     2   2      3        3
19     3   3      4        1
20     3   3      3        2
```

Comment: this is so easy! thanks so much.

Comment: Great it helped. Please consider the answer to accept or upvote if it helped you. :)  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers